# Restart and Shutdown Icon on Desktop or Favourites in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: icons, shutdown, reboot

I would like to check if there is possibility to put Shutdown and Restart icons to Favourites and on Desktop in Ubuntu. When I search in available applications there are  black icons Restart and Shutdown. All nice, when I click on those it shows confirmation for Restart/Shutdown. However when I try to add them to Favourites by right clicking (as works for other applications), there is no such option.

Could you help with adding this to Favourites or even better to Desktop?

Best Regards

PS. I somewhat recreated this behaviour with custom one-click "brute" icons. See below, but those just shutdown/restart without any confirmation (and warning that for example there is unsaved text file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=SHUTDOWN
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Exec=shutdown -h now
Icon=system-shutdown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following desktop launchers will allow you to shut down or restart the system:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Shut Down
Comment=Shut down the system
Icon=system-shutdown-symbolic
#Exec=gnome-session-quit --power-off
Exec=gnome-session-quit --power-off
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
Keywords=Shut down;Turn off;
```

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-session-quit --reboot
Icon=system-reboot-symbolic
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
Keywords=reboot;
Name=Restart
Comment=Restart the system
```

- Place them in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder to have them appear in the application overview. Form there, you can pin them to the dock.
- Copy them to the desktop to have them appear there.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! :D